# Delete files in the subfolder(recursively) from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have the following folder structure in S3.

```
s3://test/my-folder/test1.txt
s3://test/my-folder/test2.txt
s3://test/test3.txt
```

I want to recursively remove all files under a certain folder like `my-folder` above in golang(Don't want to delete `s3://test/test3.txt`) like the result of this command in s3cmd :

```
s3cmd --recursive s3://test/my-folder/
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Presumably that was `s3cmd rm --recursive s3://test/my-folder/`. None of the AWS SDKs to my knowledge have high-level file system features like sync, recursive execution etc.

Answer (score 4):

The code should:

- Call `ListObjectsV2()` with `Prefix: aws.String("test/my-folder/")` to obtain a list of the objects in that 'folder'
- Loop through the results and call `DeleteObject()` on each object, or create a list of the objects to delete and pass them to `DeleteObjects()`

See:

- [Amazon S3 examples using SDK for Go V2 - AWS SDK Code Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/go_2_s3_code_examples.html)
- [s3 package - github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3 - Go Packages](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#Client.DeleteObject)